# string.compareTo(anOtherString);

Tags: java, string, compare

I want to compare two strings with the method string.compareTo(anOtherString); and it delivers me a strange value... (i need an integer value between 0 and 57 for every string)
In the following example the first line delivers 2 and the second 1.

```
    System.out.println("And".compareTo("A"));
    System.out.println("Bus".compareTo("A"));
```

I expected that the first line is 1 and the second 2... Can someone explain that to me?

Is there a better possibility to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: 0 and 57?  where did that come from?  I am so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation for *String.compareTo()*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> If they have different characters at
>   one or more index positions ...
>   compareTo returns the difference of
>   the two character values at position k
>   in the two string.   If there is no
>   index position at which they differ
>   ... compareTo returns the difference
>   of the lengths of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

If the result is > 0, then the first string is greater, lexicographically by UTF-16 code unit.  If the result is < 0, then the first string is lesser, lexicographically.

You shouldn't rely on the actual value besides the sign and whether or not it is zero.

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

> **Returns**:
>   the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.

Btw, if you want locale-sensitive comparison, e.g. if you're comparing human readable text, use [java.text.Collator.compare](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.